# git cherry-pick built in option to keep original committer & author

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Is there a built in option in git cherry-pick to keep the original Author & Committer?
without using a script , especially needed when cherry-picking multiple commits.

i have found this [script](https://gist.github.com/dusenberrymw/c2cd64acb35e467100d86b385c71ff60) or [this](https://github.com/dingram/git-scripts/blob/master/scripts/git-cherry-pick-with-committer)
But both are over 2 years old

looking at the official [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)  i did not see any option 
am i missing somthing?

Comment: Sorry for the question but... why do you need to build a lying history? What is the expected practical benefit here?

Comment: i manage central branches for 45 developers , and many cherry-picks go through me in order to keep correct history i must keep original data

Comment: What are you calling "original data"? Your cherry-picked commits still have their author names and dates, only with the additional info of you committing again at the moment you cherry-pick. IF you ever needed to answer the question "who committed this the first time?" (which is *highly* unlikely), you still would be able to retrieve the info by tracking the source of the cherry-pick and read these (unchanged) data.

Comment: "i must keep original data"  committer is metadata, who made the actual commit.  Cherrypick makes new commits. You're the one doing the cherrypick. You made the new commit.

Comment: in my case my data only the original committer is not important , because it is saved when i push to the server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cherry-picking keeps the author by default anyway so there is nothing to do here.

None of these commands let you keep the committer, but the committer name and email address come from your configuration, where you can lie if you wish, so:

```
git -c user.name=bogus -c user.email=lie@example.com cherry-pick <hash>
```

will make the new commit under the given bogus name.

Setting `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` in the environment will override the current time as well.  In fact, the environment variables are a general purpose mechanism—they're how `git filter-branch` does its thing.  Hence the scripts that you found will work.  Why are you worried about them being "over 2 years old" when Git itself is well over a decade old?

Comment: i there a way of getting these values from the commit itself on a single line?

Comment: What do you mean by "on a single line"? If you want to extract the values from a commit, see the code that `git filter-branch` uses, in `set_ident` and `finish_ident`, in [the filter-branch script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-filter-branch.sh).

Comment: is it possible to extract the user.name & user.email from commit hash & pipline to create an alias for cherry-pick with commit extract?

Comment: @galsi: probably not as an *alias*. As a set of shell functions, sure. (You could make a Git alias that invokes these, but for sanity, it's better to put them into a script.)

Comment: it does not change the author of the commit, but it does add a co-author.

Answer (score 0):

bash script to modify committer after `git cherry-pick`

either to preserve the original committer
or to use author as committer
similar to `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date`

```bash
    #echo 'format = "%an\n%ae\n%at\n%ad"' # committer is author
    echo 'format = "%cn\n%ce\n%ct\n%cd"' # preserve committer
```

`git-cherry-pick-preserve-committer.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# git-cherry-pick-preserve-committer.sh

# bash script to modify committer after git cherry-pick

# either to preserve the original committer
# or to use author as committer
# similar to git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date

#     #echo 'format = "%an\n%ae\n%at\n%ad"' # committer is author
#     echo 'format = "%cn\n%ce\n%ct\n%cd"' # preserve committer

set -e

# preserve committer in "git cherry-pick"

function git_cherry_pick_preserve_committer() {

  # only modify commits of the "git cherry-pick"
  local head_before_cherry_pick=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

  # -x: append "(cherry picked from commit ...)" to the original commit message
  local args=(git cherry-pick -x "$@")
  echo -n "running:"; printf " %q" "${args[@]}"; echo
  "${args[@]}"

  # run "git filter-repo" to postprocess the "git cherry-pick"

  # Python code body for processing commit objects
  commit_callback=$(
    #echo 'print("locals", locals())'

    echo 'message_lines = commit.message.split(b"\n")'
    #echo 'print("message_lines", repr(message_lines))'
    echo 'try:'
    echo '  picked_from = message_lines[-2].decode("ascii")'
    echo 'except IndexError:'
    echo '  return'
    echo 'if not picked_from.startswith("(cherry picked from commit "):'
    echo '  return'

    # print newline after "Parsed 123 commits"
    #echo 'print()'

    #echo 'print("message_lines", repr(message_lines))'
    echo 'assert len(picked_from) == 68, f"unexpected picked_from: {repr(picked_from)}"'
    echo 'picked_from = picked_from[27:-1]'

    #echo 'for a in ["author_date", "author_email", "author_name", "message", "branch", "id", "old_id", "original_id", "parents", "type"]:'
    #echo '  print(f"commit.{a}", repr(getattr(commit, a)))'

    #echo 'print("picked_from", repr(picked_from))'

    # _do_not_use_this_var is passed via callback_metadata
    # lets use it! :P
    # we only need repo_filter._repo_working_dir
    # 'commit_rename_func': <bound method RepoFilter._translate_commit_hash of <git_filter_repo.RepoFilter object at ...>>
    echo 'repo_filter = _do_not_use_this_var["commit_rename_func"].__self__'
    #echo 'print("repo_filter", repo_filter)'

    #echo 'format = "%an\n%ae\n%at\n%ad"' # committer is author
    echo 'format = "%cn\n%ce\n%ct\n%cd"' # preserve committer

    echo 'args = ["git", "show", "-s", f"--format=format:{format}", picked_from]'
    #echo 'print("args", repr(args))'
    echo 'proc = subproc.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=repo_filter._repo_working_dir)'
    echo 'lines = proc.stdout.read().splitlines()'
    echo 'if len(lines) != 4:'
    echo '  print("lines", repr(lines))'
    echo '  raise Exception(f"not found picked_from commit {picked_from}")'
    echo 'commit.committer_name = lines[0]'
    echo 'commit.committer_email = lines[1]'
    echo 'commit.committer_date = lines[2] + lines[3][-6:]' # timestamp + timezone

    echo 'message_lines = message_lines[:-2]' # remove "cherry picked from" line
    echo 'commit.message = b"\n".join(message_lines)'
    #echo 'print("commit.message", repr(commit.message))'
  )

  # preserve-commit-hashes
  # fix: fatal: bad object xxx
  # git-filter-repo patches hashes in commit.message

  git filter-repo \
    --force \
    --preserve-commit-hashes \
    --commit-callback "$commit_callback" \
    --refs "$head_before_cherry_pick..HEAD"

}

git_cherry_pick_preserve_committer "$@"
```